# Google Cloud SQL Pricing

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am an avid user of Amazon AWS but I am not sure about the RDS as compared to Google's Cloud SQL. In this site - it is mentioned that Per Use Billing Plan exists.

How is that calculated? It is mentioned 'charged for periods of continuous use, rounded up to the nearest hour'.

How does it go? If there are no visitors to my site there are no charges, right? What if I say I have 100 continuous users for 30 days. Will I still be billed $0.025 per hour (excluding the network usage charges)?

How do I upload my present SQL database to Google Cloud service? Is it the same way as Amazon using Oracle Workbench?

Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about vendor pricing and product information. It should be addressed to the vendor via their pre-sales or support email instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the per use billing, if your database isn't access for 15 minutes then it is taken offline and you are only charged for data storage ($0.24 per GB per month). Its brought back online the next time it's accessed, which typically takes around a second for a D1 instance. The number of users doesn't affect the charge: you are charged for the database instance, not the user.

More details here
https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#how_usage_calculated

More information on importing data here:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/import-export

Comment: I'm using second generation Cloud SQL for testing purpose with no data no connection application. But google charge me for every second 24 hours a day(98.629 hour in 4 days) with 30% discount, so google charge me $1.16 for F1_MICRO instance and $0.12 for 1.37G storage of not data stored, no usage.

Comment: @SeSong So $1.28 per 4 days or ~$9.60/mo? That seems a little high too me. A $5 DigitalOcean droplet should suffice for a relatively low traffic site, plus you can host everything else on there too.

Comment: @SeSong MySQL Second Generation and PostgreSQL instances: You are charged per minute for the time that your instance is on: https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#how_usage_calculated

Comment: I can confirm also that Google's Cloud SQL charges for every hour even when there is no access to the database. We have just been charged 744 hours of use (whole 31 days of the month) for our dev database which is not used for 99% of time. This seems ridiculous and totally negates their "charged for what you use" idea. I have contacted them about it, and have been told one of their "technical specialist" will get in touch with me.

Comment: You lose a lot of money quickly unless you set it up correctly. GCP's SQL databases run 24/7 unless you manually start them up and shut them down https://medium.com/@the-bumbling-developer/can-you-use-google-cloud-platform-gcp-cheaply-and-safely-86284e04b332

Answer (score 4):

For Google Cloud SQL, I think we need to differentiate the MySQL 1st generation and the 2nd generation. In this FAQ link (answered by Joe Faith), https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#how_usage_calculated, it is about the 1st generation with activation policy of ON_DEMAND, meaning that you are charged per minute of usage.

However, with MySQL 2nd generation (as answered by Se Song), it will charge you entirely every minute (24 h per day) regardless whether you have active connections or not. The reason is that it uses the instance with activation policy = ALWAYS. You can read more the pricing details in here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing/#2nd-gen-pricing

Answer (score 0):

You can manually stop and restart your database instance, and hence it could be possible to write a script that activates it under particular circumstances, but this is not provided within GCP's features.

Watch the default settings carefully or you risk $350/month fees. Here's my experience: https://medium.com/@the-bumbling-developer/can-you-use-google-cloud-platform-gcp-cheaply-and-safely-86284e04b332